# Nginx: Rewrite Rules Not Working For Images

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I'm getting tons of the below errors, all the errors are pointing to images that don't actually exist at the location that an error is being given, they are rewrites in Nginx that were converted from Apache.

All was working fine in Apache, it's just since I switched over to Nginx that the images aren't displaying, all other rewrite rules which are just urls all work fine, only the images are breaking?!

**Error**

`2017/04/02 23:15:16 [error] 27629#0: *6 open() "/var/www/html/media/images/blog/10_1.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: www.website.com, request: "GET /media/images/blog/10_1.png HTTP/1.1", host: "www.website.com", referrer: "https://www.website.com/blog/"`

**Apache Rewrite Rules:**

```
## Images
RewriteRule ^media/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_([^-]+)_([^-]+)\.png$ /img.php?prefix=$1&refId=$2&thumb=$3&iid=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^media/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_([^-]+)\.png$ /img.php?prefix=$1&refId=$2&thumb=$3 [L]

## Blog Pages
RewriteRule ^blog/$ /?action=blog [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?action=blog&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?action=blog&category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

**Nginx Rewrite Rules**

```
location /media { 
    rewrite ^/media/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_([^-]+)_([^-]+)\.png$ /img.php?prefix=$1&refId=$2&thumb=$3&iid=$4 last; 
    rewrite ^/media/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_([^-]+)\.png$ /img.php?prefix=$1&refId=$2&thumb=$3 last; 
}
location /blog { 
    rewrite ^/blog/$ /?action=blog last;
    rewrite ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?action=blog&category=$1 last; 
    rewrite ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?action=blog&category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 last; 
}
```

**Fix**

```
location ^~ /media/images { 
    rewrite ^/media/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_([^-]+)_([^-]+)\.png$ /img.php?prefix=$1&refId=$2&thumb=$3&iid=$4 last; 
    rewrite ^/media/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_([^-]+)\.png$ /img.php?prefix=$1&refId=$2&thumb=$3 last; 
}
location /blog/ { 
    rewrite ^/blog/$ /?action=blog last;
    rewrite ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?action=blog&category=$1 last; 
    rewrite ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?action=blog&category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 last; 
}
```

Comment: add `/` to location prefixes `location /media/` and precise regexps for the filename, eg `^/media/images/([^/]+)/(\d+)_(\d+)\.png$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a conflicting `location` block in your configuration file, which matches any URI ending with `.png`.

You can make the `location /media` block have a higher precedence than regular expression location blocks by adding a `^~` modifier.

For example:

```
location ^~ /media { 
    rewrite ^/media/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_([^-]+)_([^-]+)\.png$ /img.php?prefix=$1&refId=$2&thumb=$3&iid=$4 last; 
    rewrite ^/media/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_([^-]+)\.png$ /img.php?prefix=$1&refId=$2&thumb=$3 last; 
}
location ^~ /blog { 
    rewrite ^/blog/$ /?action=blog last;
    rewrite ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?action=blog&category=$1 last; 
    rewrite ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?action=blog&category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 last; 
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction, I've updated my question with the fix that worked for me.